# Linq search for any of words in term

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a requirement to search an IQueryable list for the words in a search term.

Currently I have this working but it is for an exact match.

```
list.Where(x => x.MyList.Any(y => y.ToSearch.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())));
```

What I need is if someone searched for "search term" results should be:

"terms of search"
"another search term"

I am not sure the best way to go about this in linq can anyone help please?

Comment: There are some algorithms which can compare strings even if they are not exactly the same. [Here's an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//split the search terms by space
var searchWords = searchTerm.ToLower().Split( " ".ToCharArray(), 
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

//check if any of those search terms is present
list.Where(x => x.MyList.Any(y => 
        searchWords.All(sw=>y.ToSearch.ToLower().Contains(sw))));
```

Comment: I would do the `ToLower()` in the split to be slightly more performant: `var searchWords = searchTerm.ToLower().Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @AD.Net thanks for the quick response, it is nearly what I need, what if I need to match all the words in searchWords?

Comment: @Burt, I've changed `searchWords.Any` to `searchWords.All`, that should match all `searchWords`.

Comment: You win :) Thanks again for the quick response